# Jquery Validation check username with remote

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation, laravel

I am using the validation plugin and Laravel 4.2.
I try to check the username via ajax, but I can't get it work. 
The username can always be taken, doesn't matter if exists or not.

My second issue is if I am using the validation rule remote, I can't submit the form.

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong? Because in the chrome log all is fine, the request is sent and I can see the debug messages.

Php

```
<?php 
use App\Models\User;
class ValidationController extends BaseController {

public function getCheckUsername() 
{
    if(Request::ajax()) {
        $user = User::where('username', Input::get('username'))->get();
        if($user->count()) {
            return Response::json(array('msg' => 'true'));
        }
        return Response::json(array('msg' => 'false'));

    }

}


}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("form").validate({

rules: {
        username: {
                required: true,
                     rangelength:[3,255],
        remote: {
                url:"http://"+location.host+"/validation/checkusername",
                type: "get",
                success: function(msg){
                 if(msg.msg == 'true') {
                  console.log('exists');
                  return true;
                 }
                 console.log('doesnt exists');
                  return false;
                }

                },


                },
  messages: {
            username: {
                required: "Please Enter Username!",
                remote: "Username already in use!"
            }
        }
});
});
```

I also tried to create an own rule via $.validator.addMethod(), but this doens't work either.

Comment: Is this a cross domain ajax request?

Comment: No, it isn't. It's the same domain as you can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like you are sending the data. Try this. Note the post request. Also I believe the dataFilter method should return `'true'`.

**Update** I just also realized the logic in your php is sending back true if the user exists, therefore the logic in the javascript should be like so:

```
remote: {
    url: "http://"+location.host+"/validation/checkusername",
    type: "post",
    data: {
        username: function () {
            return $("input[name='username']").val();
        }
    },
    dataFilter: function (data) {
        var json = JSON.parse(data);
        if (json.msg == "true") {
            return "\"" + "That username is taken" + "\"";
        } else {
            return 'true';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Data is sending through get.
You fixed one issue, now I can send the form if it's valid. But still the remote function doesn't work.

Comment: What does the response to the ajax call say in your developer tools console network tab?

Comment: I just updated I realized that both might be returning true due to your msg being true as well.

Comment: 200. So it's fine. I tried your updated solution, but still the same problem.