# Checking Username Availability in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Is there a way to check if a username is already taken in laravel? I mean I want to check if a username is taken already without submitting the form that means checking the availability of the username while the user is typing. If there is what language should I use? And please cite examples. Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery Validation check username with remote](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24105437/jquery-validation-check-username-with-remote)

Answer (score 3):

```
$count = User::where('userName', 'like', '%Lyka%')->count();

if($count > 0)
{
  //username exists
}
else
{
  //username doesn't exist
}
```

or you can validate in laravel validation itself

```
$rules = array('username' => 'required|unique:user');

$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

if ($validator->fails()) 
{
$messages = $validator->messages()->first();
Session::put('msg',$messages);
return Redirect::back();
} else {
// username not exist
}
```

unique:user => unique from the table called user
username => is the column of the table user

Answer (score 1):

A better approach would be to use `laravel validation`. Use ajax to send the input to laravel backend. And then somewhere in your controller.

```
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'username' => 'unique:users',
    ]);
```

And check if it fails

```
    if ($validator->fails()) {
       //do whatever you want to do at fail
       //possible return appropriate json with error
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to check if a username is already taken in laravel?

Yes, try some PHP like the following:

```
$count = User::where('userName', '=', 'Lyka')->count();

if($count > 0)
{
  //username exists
}
else
{
  //username doesn't exist
}
```

If you want to check asynchronously you would have to write some Javascript and use AJAX to check while the user is filling out the form.

> If there is what language should I use?

PHP obviously and Javascript.

Good luck.